# Installing nodejs fro react native

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, react-native

I am trying following from  [official site](http://nodejs.org) with following code:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -`

`sudo apt-get install -y nodejs`

but ended with the following error:

> Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
>   Error executing command, exiting

What would be the possible solution?

Comment: i know its not really  an answer to your question but in fallback, u should try to install it via nvm https://github.com/creationix/nvm, i never install node.js this way

Comment: Thanks @ConstantinGuidon It worked :)

Answer (score 1):

From the commands above, it is obvious you are on Debian Linux Distro,
enter the following commands on your terminal to install NodeJS:

- sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall
- sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
- curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.31.0/install.sh | bash

=> Close and reopen your terminal, then enter the following commands on your terminal:

- command -v nvm
- nvm install 5.0
- nvm use 5.0
- nvm alias default node

The above will install version 5.0 of NodeJS on your box.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I solved problem with the comment given in  above question. Your answer will be reference and can be passed to other user, Appreciated bro :)